# Make list item fit its contents

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following list in HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li><span class="button">A</span></li>
    <li><span class="button">B</span></li>
    <li><span class="button">C</span></li>
</ul>
```

The accompanying CSS. Understand that I want to use differently sized buttons for different lists.

```
.button
{
    background: blue;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

The li's do not expand to fit the spans inside of them. This has the effect of throwing off the margin of the whole list, which will be especially important when I turn the list into a horizontal menu.

Also, the reason I have styled spans inside the li's instead of styling the li's themselves is because some of those spans will actually be links.

Comment: This is unclear? there is no margin above, just padding?

Comment: What you should do is to first throw away those "it will be" and make it as "it will be". Than, post your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This great article is drilling into your problem and showing what a good practise is: http://css-tricks.com/keep-margins-out-of-link-lists

That is, if I understood what you were aiming for, your question could be a bit clearer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I fixed things by adding `display: block` to my button class (`display: inline-block` for horizontal lists`).

Comment: Keep in mind that inline-block does not function as expected on older browsers. I myself still use display: inline and float: left combination on production sites for this reason. On smaller projects I could give a rats ass about old IE :)

Answer (score 3):

You must declare the `span` as an Blockelement with `display:block;`

Is it the solution for you?